# Find the longest substring match of the a string in a given base string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the logic, could you please anyone help me.

The program will take two string inputs.first is the base string, second is the search string . program needs to print longest substring of the search string that match in base string.

Input:

```
Base String :"YHKKGFFADGIJJ"
Search String:"ADGFFF"

Output:"ADG"
```

Comment: I would use `String.contains()`, start with the full search string and try ever shorter substrings until `contains` returns true. It will eventually since all strings contain the empty string.

Comment: There are multiple algorithms for searching matches. You can modify each of them to return the longest partial match. A naive algorithm shifts a pattern window across the input and checks each character of the window from left to right. You can just remember the longest partial match. Select your favorite matching algorithm and modify it for a good time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String searchLongestPattern (String base, String pattern)
{
    for (int endOffset = pattern.length() ; endOffset >= 1 ; endOffset--)
    {
        String match = null;
        if (base.indexOf(match = pattern.substring(0, endOffset)) != -1 || base.indexOf(match = pattern.substring(pattern.length() - endOffset + 1)) != -1)
        {
            return match;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the responce. But your code is failing for some test cases.                                                                                                                                  Base String  ="fhkkkADGFFjjj"                                                               Search String ="JJADGFF"                                                                                    Expected Output :"ADG"                                                                              Your out Put :null

Comment: @SiddeshHK you can try the new version

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing this solution: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Java